# ajax- update data inside a script tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, charts

I have an ajax script that create a script tag.

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../inc/ajaxadvchartupdate.php",
       data: { selected_lparr: selected_lp },
       cache: false,
       success: function(arr) {
           var code = arr;
           var script = document.createElement('script');
           script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
           script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
           document.body.appendChild(script);
           return true;
       }
    });
```

this script create a Moriss.js chart content.

The issue is that every time i call the ajax function a new script tag appends.
What is the best practice in order to update the script when I activate the ajax call.

this the output os the `success` block

```
<script type="text/javascript">


Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: [{"D":"2016-09-17","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-09-19","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-10-03","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-10-21","33":"8"},{"D":"2016-10-25","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-10-26","33":"6"},{"D":"2016-10-27","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-11-03","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-11-22","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-11-23","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-11-24","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-12-04","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-12-05","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-10","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-14","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-15","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-23","33":"2"},{"D":"2017-01-13","33":"2"},{"D":"2017-01-19","33":"2"},{"D":"2017-03-14","33":"2"}],  // shorthand echo
    xkey: 'D',
    ykeys: ['33'],  // shorthand echo
    labels: ['33'],  // shorthand echo
    stacked: false
});


</script>
```

After activating the ajax call again in order to add another value in the `data`, `ykeys` and `xkeys` this is what I get, an additional script tag is appended:

```
<script type="text/javascript" style="user-select: auto;">
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: [{"D":"2016-09-17","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-09-19","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-10-03","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-10-21","33":"8"},{"D":"2016-10-25","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-10-26","33":"6"},{"D":"2016-10-27","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-11-03","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-11-22","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-11-23","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-11-24","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-12-04","33":"4"},{"D":"2016-12-05","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-10","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-14","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-15","33":"2"},{"D":"2016-12-23","33":"2"},{"D":"2017-01-13","33":"2"},{"D":"2017-01-19","33":"2"},{"D":"2017-03-14","33":"2"}],  // shorthand echo
    xkey: 'D',
    ykeys: ['33'],  // shorthand echo
    labels: ['33'],  // shorthand echo
    stacked: false
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: [{"D":"2016-09-17","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-09-19","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-10-03","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-10-21","33":"8","34":0},{"D":"2016-10-25","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-10-26","33":"6","34":0},{"D":"2016-10-27","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-11-03","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2016-11-22","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-11-23","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2016-11-24","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-12-04","33":"4","34":0},{"D":"2016-12-05","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2016-12-10","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2016-12-14","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2016-12-15","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2016-12-23","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2017-01-13","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2017-01-19","33":"2","34":0},{"D":"2017-03-14","33":"2","34":0}],  // shorthand echo
    xkey: 'D',
    ykeys: ['33','34'],  // shorthand echo
    labels: ['33','34'],  // shorthand echo
    stacked: false
});
</script>
```

How can I replace the script tag content with the newly created one?
I know that append is not the correct answer. 
any suggestion will be great!

Comment: You can do is check and delete and then create a new dom content

Comment: How can i delete a script tag, How do i select it? I mean, it has no id.

Comment: Just instantiate new `Morris.Bar` with data from ajax-response

Comment: You mean create a new chart? I want to have one chart and that it will be updated on ajax call. now, all works great except the part in the question.

Comment: I tried something and found alternative way.  Don't create a  script every time. instead create a div which only contains data to be shown on chart. In morris bar read the data from that div and create chart. Because the ajax don't actually write in code  neither does it delete hence i don't think its possible the way you are doing.

Comment: @DavSev something like this :  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../inc/ajaxadvchartupdate.php",
       data: { selected_lparr: selected_lp },
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
          //Only data part of the chart
$("#hidden_div").text(""); $("#hidden_div").text(data);}});
var graph_data = $("#hidden_div").text();
if(len(graph_data)==0){
  Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: graph_data,  // shorthand echo
    xkey: 'D',
    ykeys: ['33'],  // shorthand echo
    labels: ['33'],  // shorthand echo
    stacked: false
  });
}

Comment: Well, This is definetley a better solution than the one I tought of !

Comment: The Idea is great, But I cant get the data be placed in the Morris.Bar JSON.